# CSS overlay not scrolling

Tags: html, css

I have a CSS overlay with a picture in the center.
My problem is, this picture will always be big and I need to scroll this picture inside overlay to see the rest of it.

but what happen is that when I scroll, I'm scrolling the page behind overlay.
what is wrong in this?

CSS

```
#imgfull{
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 z-index: 10;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
 text-align:center;
}
#imgfull img{
 max-width:90%;
 margin-top:55px;
 box-shadow:0 0 25px #111;
 -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 25px #111;
 -moz-box-shadow:0 0 25px #111;
 z-index:100;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="imgfull">

<img src="http://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/%C3%A1rvore-isolada-1821590.jpg">

</div>

<div><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zo78e2dt/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `overflow-y: scroll` to `#imgfull` to make the div scroll independently of the rest of the page.

http://jsfiddle.net/zo78e2dt/5/

Comment: oh, yeah, but in this case when I scroll down the page the overlay have a problem not covering all page anymore ;/

Comment: @renata costa I edited the answer to try to fix it. See if that's what you want.

Answer (score 0):

if i have understand is like this ?

i have used  a new container for photo called "over" with this css:

```
.over {overflow-y:auto;
height:100%;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/s2h1ecLp/